# How do I filter out data from a string in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, subprocess, wmi-query

I have a program that runs a WMI query through PowerShell and gets the output and stores it in a string, then prints it. When I run it I get this blob of text. I can make out the values I want (Name, SensorType, and Value). But there's a ton of other junk in there.

> b'\r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : Memory\r\nSensorType       : Load\r\nValue            : 40.99033\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Core #2\r\nSensorType       : Temperature\r\nValue            : 62\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : Used Space\r\nSensorType       : Load\r\nValue            : 92.39651\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Core #1\r\nSensorType       : Temperature\r\nValue            : 62\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU DRAM\r\nSensorType       : Power\r\nValue            : 1.471058\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Core #2\r\nSensorType       : Load\r\nValue            : 55.46875\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Package\r\nSensorType       : Power\r\nValue            : 12.19472\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : Bus Speed\r\nSensorType       : Clock\r\nValue            : 100.0001\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Total\r\nSensorType       : Load\r\nValue            : 51.5625\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Package\r\nSensorType       : Temperature\r\nValue            : 62\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Core #2\r\nSensorType       : Clock\r\nValue            : 3100.004\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : Temperature\r\nSensorType       : Temperature\r\nValue            : 34\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : Used Memory\r\nSensorType       : Data\r\nValue            : 3.240162\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : Available Memory\r\nSensorType       : Data\r\nValue            : 4.664536\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Core #1\r\nSensorType       : Clock\r\nValue            : 3100.004\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Cores\r\nSensorType       : Power\r\nValue            : 7.794704\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Graphics\r\nSensorType       : Power\r\nValue            : 2.226472\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n__GENUS          : 2\r\n__CLASS          : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS     : \r\n__DYNASTY        : \r\n__RELPATH        : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION     : {}\r\n__SERVER         : \r\n__NAMESPACE      : \r\n__PATH           : \r\nName             : CPU Core #1\r\nSensorType       : Load\r\nValue            : 47.65625\r\nPSComputerName   : \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n'

Here is the PowerShell Script,

```
function NSV(){
$computer = "LocalHost"
$namespace = "root\OpenHardwareMonitor"
$property1 = "Name"
$property2 = "SensorType"
$property3 = "Value"
Get-WmiObject -class Sensor -computername $computer -namespace $namespace -Property $property1,$property2,$property3
}
```

And here is the Python Script,

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", ". \"./TestScript\";", "&NSV"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
print (output)
```

I'm pretty new to this stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Why don't you `ConvertTo-Json` the output in PowerShell?

Comment: I’m not familiar with that command. Where would I implement that line on my .ps1

Comment: Simply append to the end of `Get-WmiObject  .... | ConverTo-Json`

Comment: Seems simple enough I’ll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try regex, like this:

```
import re

for match in re.finditer('SensorType', str(yourstring)):
    print("%s: %s" % (match.start(), match.group()))
```

Here the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

You can put your binary text into a string, split at newlines and filter those that start with what you specify:

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe", ". \"./TestScript\";", "&NSV"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(output, err) = p.communicate()
data = str(output) 

# data =str(b'\r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : Memory\r\nSensorType : Load\r\nValue : 40.99033\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Core #2\r\nSensorType : Temperature\r\nValue : 62\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : Used Space\r\nSensorType : Load\r\nValue : 92.39651\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Core #1\r\nSensorType : Temperature\r\nValue : 62\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU DRAM\r\nSensorType : Power\r\nValue : 1.471058\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Core #2\r\nSensorType : Load\r\nValue : 55.46875\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Package\r\nSensorType : Power\r\nValue : 12.19472\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : Bus Speed\r\nSensorType : Clock\r\nValue : 100.0001\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Total\r\nSensorType : Load\r\nValue : 51.5625\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Package\r\nSensorType : Temperature\r\nValue : 62\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Core #2\r\nSensorType : Clock\r\nValue : 3100.004\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : Temperature\r\nSensorType : Temperature\r\nValue : 34\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : Used Memory\r\nSensorType : Data\r\nValue : 3.240162\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : Available Memory\r\nSensorType : Data\r\nValue : 4.664536\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Core #1\r\nSensorType : Clock\r\nValue : 3100.004\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Cores\r\nSensorType : Power\r\nValue : 7.794704\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Graphics\r\nSensorType : Power\r\nValue : 2.226472\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n__GENUS : 2\r\n__CLASS : Sensor\r\n__SUPERCLASS : \r\n__DYNASTY : \r\n__RELPATH : \r\n__PROPERTY_COUNT : 3\r\n__DERIVATION : {}\r\n__SERVER : \r\n__NAMESPACE : \r\n__PATH : \r\nName : CPU Core #1\r\nSensorType : Load\r\nValue : 47.65625\r\nPSComputerName : \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n')

whatIwant = ["Name","SensorType","Value"]
d = [ q for q in data.split("\r\n") if any(q.startswith(k) for k in whatIwant)]
# put every len(whatIwant ) items into one sublist
step = len(whatIwant)
dd = [d[i:i+step] for i in range(0,len(d),step)]
for k in dd:
    print(k)
```

Output:

```
['Name : Memory', 'SensorType : Load', 'Value : 40.99033']
['Name : CPU Core #2', 'SensorType : Temperature', 'Value : 62']
['Name : Used Space', 'SensorType : Load', 'Value : 92.39651']
['Name : CPU Core #1', 'SensorType : Temperature', 'Value : 62']
['Name : CPU DRAM', 'SensorType : Power', 'Value : 1.471058']
['Name : CPU Core #2', 'SensorType : Load', 'Value : 55.46875']
['Name : CPU Package', 'SensorType : Power', 'Value : 12.19472']
['Name : Bus Speed', 'SensorType : Clock', 'Value : 100.0001']
['Name : CPU Total', 'SensorType : Load', 'Value : 51.5625']
['Name : CPU Package', 'SensorType : Temperature', 'Value : 62']
['Name : CPU Core #2', 'SensorType : Clock', 'Value : 3100.004']
['Name : Temperature', 'SensorType : Temperature', 'Value : 34']
['Name : Used Memory', 'SensorType : Data', 'Value : 3.240162']
['Name : Available Memory', 'SensorType : Data', 'Value : 4.664536']
['Name : CPU Core #1', 'SensorType : Clock', 'Value : 3100.004']
['Name : CPU Cores', 'SensorType : Power', 'Value : 7.794704']
['Name : CPU Graphics', 'SensorType : Power', 'Value : 2.226472']
['Name : CPU Core #1', 'SensorType : Load', 'Value : 47.65625']
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However there are 2 issues. 1. The values change every time the program is ran. How would I make the string the output variable. 2. When I run it, I don't seem to get any errors, however nothing is printing for me

Comment: @gman1230321 you got the string already as `output` in your script ... I edited your code back in. does this not work?